# splitting whole list of strings in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of python strings which are in a list.

I want to call split method at each string in the list and store the results in another list without using loops because the list is very long.

**EDIT1**
Here is one example

```
   input = ["a,the,an","b,b,c","people,downvoting,it,must,think,first"]

   output  [["a","the","an"],["b","b","c"],["people","downvoting","it","must","think","first"]]
```

The delimiter used for splitting is ","

Any trick for this?

Comment: An example of your input and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: "without using loops because the list is very very long." What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that loops in python are very slow and the list contains a lot of strings

Comment: An example is there now

Comment: Is there any moderator to check whether people downvoting is correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
[a.split(',') for a in list]

Sample: ['a,c,b','1,2,3']
Result: [['a','c','b'],['1','2','3']]
```

If you wanted everything in one list, you could try this (not sure of how efficient it is)

```
output = sum([a.split(',') for a in list],[])
Sample: ['a,c,b','1,2,3']
Result: ['a','c','b','1','2','3']
```

Comment: Its a perfect one but still there is one loop inside

Comment: Added what should be a flat list creation there.

Comment: Using `sum` to concatenate lists will be very slow for long lists: the algorithm is quadratic.

Comment: OK. In that case, maybe use the `itertools` solution suggested as part of this

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehensions.

```
mystrings = ["hello world", "this is", "a list", "of interesting", "strings"]
splitby = " "
mysplits = [x.split(splitby) for x in mystrings]
```

No idea if it performs better than a `for` loop, but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a flat list, and not a list of lists:

```
from itertools import chain
list_out = list(reduce(chain, [string.split() for string in lists_in]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would turn the list to a string and then turn the string back to a list with the split function.
Hence running the split function only once.

`' '.join(['my', 'very', 'long', 'list']).split(' ');`